# Why do 32-bit immediates with IMUL give warnings in NASM and errors in GCC?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, gnu-assembler, immediate-operand

I am currently investigating some strange behaviour with the `imul` instruction, because the official Intel manual seems to differ slightly from reality.

The first thing I noticed is that the Intel manual does not consider this example to be a correct instruction:

```
imul rax, 2
```

yet both GCC/GAS (with `.intel_syntax noprefix`) and NASM accept this instruction without problem. Using `objdump -d` showed me this:

```
48 6b c0 02             imul   $0x2,%rax,%rax
```

meaning it gets translated into a different instruction that is in fact documented in the manual.

I already find this weird and would like to know, why this even exists. The only place I could find this documented was in the [NASM instruction set](https://nasm.us/xdoc/2.15rc9/html/nasmdocb.html) and, weirdly enough, in the Description of the `imul` instruction in the Intel manual. The latter reads:

> - **Two-operand form** — With this form the destination operand (the first operand) is multiplied by the source operand (second operand). The destination operand is a general purpose register and ***the source operand is an immediate value***, a general-purpose register, or a memory location. The intermediate product (twice the size of the input operand) is truncated and stored in the destination operand location.

That is inconsistent with the Opcode table of that same instruction.

The NASM instruction set also mentions `imul reg64, sbytedword` and `imul reg64, imm` instructions, neither of which I understand what they mean. `imm` would imply that 64-bit immediates could be used as well, would it not? And the meaning of `sbytedword` is unclear to me.

Now to the 32-bit immediates: The NASM instruction set mentions `imul reg64, imm32` while both the Intel manual and the NASM set mention `imul r64, r/m64, imm32`. However, normally when an immediate of a lower bitcount than the destination operand is used, the Intel manual specifically mentions sign-extension in the description column of the Opcode table. In this case, it is not mentioned, so I wondered what would happen if I happened to use a negative 32-bit immediate (in other words, requiring all 32 bits).

This is the assembly code I tested this with:

```
        global  imm_test

        section .text

imm_test:
        mov     rax, rdi
        imul    rax, 0xFFDFFFFF
        ret
```

Then I called the *imm_test* function from C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int imm_test(int n);

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", imm_test(1));
    return 0;
}
```

If that 32-bit immediate were to be sign-extended, the value I would assume would have to be printed is `-2097153`, which, when using NASM to assemble and GCC to compile and link, is exactly what is printed.
And yet NASM gives me this warning:

> ```
> test.asm:7: warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
> test.asm:7: warning: dword data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
> ```

However, looking at the disassembly again, the instruction is encoded exactly the way I would expect it to be:

```
48 69 c0 ff ff df ff    imul   $0xffffffffffdfffff,%rax,%rax
```

It's a 32-bit immediate sign-extended to 64-bit.

When I change the syntax of the assembly code to GAS's `.intel_syntax noprefix` like so:

```
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        .global  imm_test

        .text

imm_test:
        mov     rax, rdi
        imul    rax, 0xFFDFFFFF
        ret
```

and try to assemble this with the GNU assembler, I don't just get a warning, I get an error:

> ```
> test.S: Assembler messages:
> test.S:8: Error: operand type mismatch for `imul
> ```

Changing the `imul` instructions to the properly documented `imul rax, rax, 0xFFDFFFFF` version does not change anything.

So I'm wondering, why is the documentation for `imul` so inconsistent, and why are 32-bit immediates officially supported (and also work correctly), yet they give errors or warnings?

Comment: @Sep: I don't think OBJDUMP is a normal capitalization for that tool that's part of GNU Binutils; it's not an initialism like NASM (which yes should be capitalized).  `objdump` was actually fine, and plain objdump would also be fine.  Also, no need to capitalize Manual; it is a manual, and the usage here wasn't necessarily using it as part of the proper name of those manuals, which is Intel SDM not Intel Manual.

Comment: @PeterCordes I had my doubts about changing `objdump`. And for the capitalization of 'manual', the post had 4 counts of "Intel **M**anual" and 1 count of ""Intel **m**anual". I was just going to level these. Will now quicky change the 3 "Intel Manual" that remain.

Answer (score 3):

#### Assembly source uses *values*, not immediate bit-pattern encodings

`imul r64, r/m64, sign_extended_imm32` or imm8 are the only forms with 64-bit operand size available<sup>1</sup>; see Intel's manual (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul), so `0x0000_0000_FFDF_FFFF` is not encodeable.

But that's what `0xFFDF_FFFF` means; like with any place-value way of writing numbers, unwritten places to the left are assumed to be 0.

NASM warns about truncating, GAS simply errors with a not very helpful message, but in both cases the only problem is the numeric value of the constant. With `.intel_syntax noprefix` in GAS,  `imul  rax, rax, 0x7FDFFFFF` assembles just fine.  A signed-positive 32-bit number is not a problem.  (High bit = 0.)

`mov eax, 0xFFDF_FFFF` is encodeable because the operand-size is 32-bit, so the source operand is a raw 32-bit value that *doesn't* implicitly get sign-extended to 64-bit.

As part of executing a `mov` to EAX, [the upper 32 bits of RAX get zeroed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6).  You *could* look at it as the constant getting zero-extended to 64-bit, but that extension happens as part of a 32-bit instruction writing a 32-bit register on x86-64.  `add eax, 0xFFDF_FFFF` is a clearer case: it's doing a 32-bit add, truncating the result to 32-bit, and writing it to EAX.  Implicit zero-extension into RAX happens during that register write after the add, not while reading the inputs.  It's only with `mov` that copies a value unchanged that there's room to look at it a different way.

Either way, assemblers understand the full value you wrote, and will tell you if it's not possible to encode that value as an operand of whatever operand-size.  **Remember, assembly source uses *values*, not bit-patterns for the machine code**.  This is part of why you're using an assembler.  If you meant `0xFFFF_FFFF_FFDF_FFFF`, you should write that.

---

#### `imul rax,2` being a "separate form"?

NASM (and most other assemblers including GAS) accept `imul x, imm` as short-hand for `imul x, x, imm`.  Same for AVX instructions like `vpand xmm0, xmm0, xmm1`.

It just saves you from having to repeat the same register twice as both the destination and first source when you don't want to take advantage of the non-destructive separate destination.  There isn't a different machine encoding for that form, only assembly-level syntax, which is why you don't find it in Intel's manuals, and why disassembly shows the real form the assembler picked.

---

**Footnote 1:**  You mentioned the [NASM appendix B](https://nasm.us/xdoc/2.15rc9/html/nasmdocb.html) which shows:

```
IMUL             reg64,reg64,imm8         X64 
IMUL             reg64,reg64,sbytedword   X64,ND 
IMUL             reg64,reg64,imm32        X64 
IMUL             reg64,reg64,imm          X64,ND
```

I don't know what the point of the `ND` entries are, but `mov` is the only instruction in x86-64 that can take a 64-bit immediate.  The `imm8` and `imm32` forms are a complete enumeration of your options.  So is `sbytedword` (a signed byte or dword).  The plain unqualified `imm` is just confusing and wrong.

(NASM documents the `reg64,reg64,imm8` form separately from `reg64,imm8`, that's just NASM letting the middle operand implicitly be the same as the first operand.  The machine encoding is still `imul r64, r/m64, immediate` with two different opcodes, one for 8-bit and one for 32-bit immediate.  Same opcodes that do 32-bit and 16-bit operand-size with no or different prefixes.)

NASM's Appendix B has been wrong before, e.g. about which CPU version each form of each instruction was new in.  [This fork of NASM 2.05's appendix](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm) corrected those mistakes, and is a useful reference for that.  It still includes more text descriptions that later NASM versions removed when the instruction list got longer.  (However, it only lists 32-bit and 16-bit mode instructions, no 64-bit mode ones.)

But really I only ever refer to ecm's fork of the NASM appendix when I want to check on `imul r,r/m,imm` being new in 186, or something like that.  **If I want to know the current state of the x86 ISA**, what forms of an instruction are available, I **check Intel's manuals**.  (Or actually the HTML scraped from Intel's vol.2 PDF, on https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ .)  Intel sometimes has mistakes, but not about something that important / fundamental to the point of the manual.

Comment: I updated the insref link you specified. The domain pushbx.org is one that I myself own (albeit it is currently pointing to the same server as ulukai.org the old domain). And the "canonical" path of the insref is now /ecm/doc/.

Comment: @ecm: Ok thanks; I'll update the link in the x86 tag wiki (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) where I copied the link from.  And thanks for the copy-edit to fix left-over extra words after and other things that I missed when changing how I phrased things.

Comment: From the original 386 manual until at least 2006, the Intel SDM listed `imul r16/32/64, imm8/16/32` as synonyms for the three operand form. There is still a remnant of this even in the current SDM, which says "**Two-operand form** — ... the source operand is an *immediate value*, a general-purpose register, or a memory location."

Answer (score 1):

> Why are 32-bit immediates officially supported (and also work correctly), yet they give errors or warnings?

I assume that a 64-bit GCC compiler internally works with signed 64-bit integers.

The version I am using prints an error message because the 64-bit value `+0xFFDFFFFF` is not in the range `-0x80000000`...`+0x7FFFFFFF` and therefore cannot be converted to a 32-bit signed value!

Note: "32-bit constants are supported" does not mean that the assembler will automatically truncate constants to 32 bits if more than 32 bits are required! And you need at least 33 bits to store the value `0xFFDFFFFF` as signed number!

Writing the constant as `0xFFFFFFFFFFDFFFFFFFFF` or as `-0x200001` worked well.

Maybe the developers of NASM want that a number like `0xFFFFFFFE` is interpreted as `-2` for compatibility with older programs where `-2` can be written as `0xFFFFFFFE`;

... and the developers of GNU AS assume that a developer typing `0xFFFFFFFE` in a 64-bit program really means `+4294967294` and not `-2`.

... this means that GAS assumes that `imul rax, rax, 0xFFDFFFFF` shall have the same result as `imul rax, rbx` after a `mov rbx, 0xFFDFFFFF`.

As a consequence, GNU AS prints an error message because `imul rax, rax, immediate` cannot multiply `rax` with `+4294967294`.

> So I'm wondering, why is the documentation for `imul` so inconsistent ...

This has nothing to do with documentation:

GCC (and GNU assembler) uses a different syntax than the Intel's official syntax. "nasm" is much closer to the official syntax.

... and I think that this is documented somewhere.

Comment: The complete program is exactly the one in my original post and that should work with GCC. I am aware that the GNU assembler syntax is different, but `.intel_syntax noprefix` should resolve that. I do not understand what you mean by "you need at least 33 bits to store the value `0xFFDFFFFF`" though. `0xFFDFFFFF` is a 32-bit value, why would the assembler try to store it in 33 bits? Not to mention, nasm **does** store it in 32-bits like it should. `0xFFFFFFFFFFDFFFFFFFFF` gives me the same error and warning as well, which makes sense. 64-bit immediates are not allowed with imul.

Comment: @Treeniks: "`0xFFFFFFFFFFDFFFFFFFFF`" is `0xFFFF_FFFF_FFDF_FFFF_FFFF`. That's an 80-bit number! Anyway, `0xFFDF_FFFF` needs 33 bits because the 33rd bit needs to be a zero if we want it to sign-extend to 64-bits as `0x0000_0000_FFDF_FFFF`. As a sign-extended `imm32` it is `0xFFFF_FFFF_FFDF_FFFF` which has the same low 32 bits but has the 32-bit value's sign bit extended throughout the upper 32 bits. (NASM allows to put underscores in the number by the way, useful for readability.)

Comment: @Treeniks Ah. Sorry. Reading your question I only saw the nasm code... And I didn't know that GASM supports `noprefix`... Shame on me.

Comment: @Treeniks `0xFFDFFFFF` is an ***un***signed 32-bit number. This is true. However, signed 32-bit numbers are in the range from `-0x80000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`. And a compiler internally working with 64-bit numbers will understand `0xFFDFFFFF` as `+0xFFDFFFFF` which is definitely outside that range.

Comment: Anyway my NASM accepts both `imul rax, 0xFFFF_FFFF_FDFF_FFFF` and `imul rax,rax,dword 0xfdffffff` without a warning. The latter is the NDISASM output for both of those.

Comment: @ecm This may be an intentional decision of the developers: Maybe the NASM developers wanted to stay compatible with existing 32-bit programs where `-2` is written `0xFFFFFFFE`, and the GAS developers assumed that a person writing `0xFFFFFFFE` in a 64-bit program really means `+4294967294` and not `-2`...

Comment: @Martin Rosenau: Without the `dword` keyword, that is with the instruction `imul rax, rax, 0xfdffffff`, NASM does warn `signed dword immediate exceeds bounds` and `dword data exceeds bounds`.

Comment: @ecm `imul rax, dword 0xFFDF_FFFF` does however give the warning still. So explicitly marking the immediate as a dword seems to only work with the longer 2-register instruction. I find it weird that the assembler interprets immediates with a sign though since `mov eax, 0xFFDF_FFFF` does in fact assemble without warnings or errors. So the assembler selectively chooses when to interpret immediates with a sign depending on the instruction?

Comment: @Treeniks: Interesting that NASM warns for `imul rax, dword 0xFFDF_FFFF` indeed. And yes, the assembler does accept a signed or unsigned immediate depending on the instruction: `mov eax` takes an unsigned 32-bit immediate. `imul rax` takes a signed 32-bit immediate. (Similarly, `mov rax` can take a signed 32-bit immediate, but as opposed to `imul` there's also a genuine 64-bit immediate form for `mov r64`. And `mov rax` can be assembled into a `mov eax` by NASM for genuine 32-bit unsigned immediates because writing to `eax` always zero-extends to `rax`.)

Comment: This answer is way overcomplicated because you used `.intel_syntax` (prefix by default) instead of the question's `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  Never use `.intel_syntax prefix`, it's a mutant hybrid of AT&T decorations with Intel everything else.  Clang doesn't even support that.  The only issue is that `imul r64, r/m64, sign_extended_imm32` or imm8 are the only forms, so `0x0000_0000_FFDF_FFFF` is not encodeable (@Treeniks).  But that's what `0xFFDF_FFFF` means; like with any place-value way of writing numbers, unwritten places to the left are assumed to be 0.

Comment: @PeterCordes I mentioned `.intel_syntax` because I didn't see that the question contained the code used in GAS, so I was thinking the user tried to compile the unmodified NASM code with GAS. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Major improvement, but there's still a section at the bottom that talks about Intel vs. GAS syntax, but `.intel_syntax noprefix` uses identical syntax to NASM for this instruction with register operands.  Your original answer got into a big mess because you left out the `noprefix` part when you tried it.  The problem is that NASM's Appendix B just has some confusing nonsense showing 4 different entries for 64-bit operand size, not the actual 2.  i.e. NASM has its own documentation, but it's wrong or misleading.

Comment: Also, you suggest that *Maybe the developers of NASM want that a number like 0xFFFFFFFE is interpreted as -2 for compatibility with older programs*.  But no, NASM *does* warn about this, as you can see in the quote from the question: `warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds`.  The fact that they choose to warn instead of error might be due to compatibility motivations, or just different design philosophy.